# Get checkboxes on the page with jQuery and put the values into string to send ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is use jQuery to grab any checkboxes that are checked on the page. The boxes are dynamically created using a specific ID number of each one for the ID and Value.

What is the easiest way about getting it to grab the values of each checked item? Then check if less than or greater than 3 is checked. If only 3 are checked then send the values of each checkbox to my php script. I'm using a regular button on the page so I will proably have to use the .click method since its not actually part of a form to submit.
I've seen several examples around here but not quite what I'm trying to do.

```
$('#mybtn').live('click',function(){         
       $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
       // I guess do something here.
)};
)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code i believe you are wanting is this

```
$('#mybtn').live('click',function(){  
    var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    var checkbox_values = new Array();
    if( num_checked > 3 ) {
        //its greater than 3
        //do what you need to do
    } else if( num_checked < 3 ) {
        //its less than 3
        //do what you need to do
    }else {
        //it equals 3
        //do what you need to do

        //go thru and add values to array
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            checkbox_values.push($(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

if you want to send email of variables you can output array checkbox_values to php

Comment: This works well, but how do you get the array to update in the ajax call without it doing an ajax call for each value. Right now if I alert the array it gives me an alert for each value.

Comment: if you want to alert full array you want to alert outside the each() function. Do have any code written already for your ajax call?

Comment: I tried to alert outside and kept getting a JS error. Undefined function. Thx

Comment: ah... I changed it and moved the var checkbox_values = new Array();  outside of the each function and now it works. Thanks. If you can edit that so the var array is declared outside of the each function it work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: oh move this variable declaration to top with other: var checkbox_values = new Array(); EDIT: Did see you posted that above me

Comment: I did figure it out after thinking about it(the js error). Thanks for help exactly what I needed to get movin again.

Comment: Using $.map could help fetching values without manually iterating the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

If all your checkboxes are in a form, you can do `$('#form_id').serialize();`

Comment: +1 serialize() is certainly the easiest way to grab values in a form: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ You can easily refine your selection, for example: $("form input:visible").serialize();

Answer (score 0):

You can get how many are checked using

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKRRL/7/

Not really sure what you want to do with the ones that are checked, but the js fiddle loops through the checked ones. From there you could grab id's etc.

full code

```
$(function() {
    $('#mybtn').live('click', function() {
        var checkedBoxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"),
            checkedNum = checkedBoxes.length;

        if(checkedNum  === 3){
            for(var i=0; i< checkedNum; i++){
               alert($(checkedBoxes).eq(i).val());
            } 
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to grab all checked checkboxes:

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
  count = checked.length;

if (count == 3) {
  values = $.map(checked, function(i){
    return $(this).val();
  });
}
```

Then do whatever you want on the values array.